# How do I load OS Variables into PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

This should be pretty straightforward but the search words are so common that I am not finding an answer:

Q.  How do I load the values from an operating system variable (RHEL) into PL/SQL on an Oracle 11g database?

Code:

```
begin
dba_utilities.utilities_with_ext_proc.send_email(
        p_recipient   => '$MAIL_LIST',
        p_subject     => 'Subject'
        p_body        => 'Body
);
End ;
```

The procedure works fine if I put in an email address but there is a system variable called $MAIL_LIST that contains a group of people.  I can also confirm that this is working on other servers but I am setting up a replacement.

Thanks in advance and sorry if the question is overly simple!

Comment: The $MAIL_LIST variable is available in command line to the operating system user that started the Oracle Database .

Comment: What is your procedure doing.  Based on the package name, I would guess that you have some sort of external procedure declared.  That implies that PL/SQL is calling out to an external procedure written in C (or something that exposes a C interface) and implies that the resolution of the environment variable is being done in that external procedure, not in PL/SQL.  If that's the case, we'd need to figure out how the external procedure is defined and implemented.  Where in your environment is this environment variable being populated?

Comment: The PL/SQL is calling a shell command as shown below:

shell('echo "Subject: '||REPLACE(p_subject, '"', '\"')||CHR(10)||l_body||'" | sendmail '||p_recipient);

I need to try the answer below to see if it works or not.

Comment: The shell command being called is defined as follows (in another procedure):

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE shell(cmd IN char)
    AS EXTERNAL 
       NAME "sh"
       LIBRARY shell_lib
       LANGUAGE C
       PARAMETERS (cmd string);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the environment variables via the [`getenv` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28%29) in Java's [`System` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html). To invoke this from PL/SQL, you can create a Java stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getenv(name VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
  AS LANGUAGE JAVA 
  NAME 'java.lang.System.getenv(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
```

Now, you can write your PL/SQL code as follows:

```
begin
dba_utilities.utilities_with_ext_proc.send_email(
        p_recipient   => getenv('MAIL_LIST'),
        p_subject     => 'Subject'
        p_body        => 'Body
);
End ;
```

The stored procedure can also exist inside a PL/SQL package (if you don't want to create a schema-level function just to acquire environment variables).